# IO Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python

have a script in which I am trying to extract two different flows from one site and put it in 2 different files. Unfortunately only 1 output file is generated and I get the errormessage:

Cleaning data..._LiveChat_agents

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_Prog\Customer_Care\LiveChat+Chats.py", line 45, in <module>
    with open(messages, 'w') as outfile:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'LiveChat_agents14-12-2018.json'`

this is my script: 
*from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings
import requests
import re
import os
import json
import datetime
import logging
#authenitcation service-to-service-to-serv
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='datalake', account_key='XXXXXX'
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
logs = 'C:\\Python_Execution\\Log\\'
os.chdir(logs)
if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.makedirs(today)
file_out = "C:\\Python_Execution\\Temp"
os.chdir(file_out)
#authenticate
#url = 'https://api.livechatinc.com/v2/chats'
headers = {'X-API-Version': '2',}
response_agents = requests.get('https://api.livechatinc.com/agents', headers=headers, auth=('jdoe@whatever.com', '000'))
#print(response_agents.text)
response_agents_toclean = response_agents.text
response_agents_clean = response_agents_toclean.encode('utf-8')
logging.info('Writing data to local file')
response_agents_final = json.loads(response_agents_clean)
messages = 'LiveChat_agents' + today +'.json'
print('Cleaning data..._LiveChat_agents')
response_agents_final = json.loads(response_agents_clean)
with open(messages, 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(response_agents_final, outfile)

#extract Chats
response_chats = requests.get('https://api.livechatinc.com/chats', headers=headers, auth=('jdoe@whatever.com', '000'))
#print(response_chats.text)
response_chats_toclean = response_chats.text
response_chats_clean = response_chats_toclean.encode('utf-8')
logging.info('Writing data to local file')
response_chats_final = json.loads(response_chats_clean)
messages = 'LiveChat_chats' + today +'.json'
print('Cleaning data...LiveChat_chats')
response_chats_final = json.loads(response_chats_clean)
with open(messages, 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(response_chats_final, outfile)

   print('Uploading to blob storage...')
logging.info('Uploading to blob storage')
blob_container = 'landing-livechat'
#Upload the CSV file to Azure cloud
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
    blob_container,
    messages,
    file_out + '\\' + messages,
    content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/JSON')
            )
# Check the list of blob
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(blob_container)
for blob in generator:
    print(blob.name)
logging.info('Upload completed successfully')
print('Deleting temp file...')
logging.info('Deleting temp file')
os.chdir(file_out)
os.remove(messages)
logging.info('Completed Sucessfully!')*
```

appreciate your help.
gracias
M

Comment: do you have write permission on directory where you are trying to create file?

Comment: Also that should not be open already on your computer.

Comment: have permission as I can create 1 output file (in this case the part that generates Chats) and the file is not opened

Comment: The fact that you can create another file in the same directory doesn't mean you have the right to open _this_ file for writing so you have to check the permissions more carefully.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, but how can I see/check this in python??